# How to access a Dictionary passed via NSNotification, using Swift

Tags: dictionary, notifications, swift

I have code that sends a notification (where serialNumber is a String):

```
  var dataDict = Dictionary<String, String>()
  dataDict["Identity"] = serialNumber
  dataDict["Direction"] = "Add"
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("deviceActivity", object:self, userInfo:dataDict)
```

And code that receives this notification:

```
  func deviceActivity(notification: NSNotification) {

     // This method is invoked when the notification is sent
     // The problem is in how to access the Dictionary and pull out the entries
  }
```

I've tried a variety of code to accomplish this, with no success:

```
let dict = notification.userInfo
let dict: Dictionary<String, String> = notification.userInfo
let dict: Dictionary = notification.userInfo as Dictionary
```

And while some of my attempts satisfy the compiler, none have yielded actual Strings when trying to access what has been extracted as a Dictionary:

```
let sn : String = dict["Identity"]!
let sn : String = dict.valueForKey("Identity") as String
let sn : String = dict.valueForKey("Identity")
```

So the question is this:  How do I write Swift code to extract an object, in this case a Dictionary, that was passed via a notification, and access the component parts of that object (in this case the keys and values)?

Answer (score 42):

As notification.userInfo type is AnyObject ayou must downcast it to appropriate dictionary type.

After exact type of dictionary is known you don't need to downcast values you get from it. But you may want to check if values are actually present in dictionary before using them:

```
// First try to cast user info to expected type
if let info = notification.userInfo as? Dictionary<String,String> {
  // Check if value present before using it
  if let s = info["Direction"] {
    print(s)
  }
  else {
    print("no value for key\n")
  }
}
else {
  print("wrong userInfo type")
}
```

Comment: always hit's the print("wrong userInfo type") - in swift 2

Comment: @Async- It works for me in playground. You need to make sure that all your keys and values are strings however. If you have different types you will need to change types in 1st cast

Comment: sorry, yes it works - after reset content of simulator, clean and build it works!

Comment: Works great!  Thank you.

Comment: Value of type 'UNNotification' has no member 'userInfo' in 4.9.19

Comment: @ScottyBlades UNNotification is a different API from NSNotification

Comment: @Vladimir  my bad!

Answer (score 12):

You should use structure like `[NSObject : AnyObject]` and retrieve value as from NSDictionary `yourLet[key]`

```
func keyboardWillShown(notification : NSNotification){
    let tmp : [NSObject : AnyObject] = notification.userInfo!
    let duration : NSNumber = tmp[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as NSNumber
    let scalarDuration : Double = duration.doubleValue
}
```